Why embed code is not displaying correctly mobile view?
The embed board from a job board app is not displaying correctly in mobile: https://sirena.tours/hiring/
There is an overflow on the right side. One of the fields and view more button cannot be seen unless you scroll on the right.
Can anyone help?
I have no coding skills.

You'll likely have to take this up with the provider of that widget.

Unfortunately, they haven't replied for quite a while now.

I see some inline css codes at the place where you add the iframe.

If you remove this line I circled with red - width: auto and replace it with width: 100% !important it will be working.

Still looks the same.

It is already set to width: 100% !important;, when I emulate a mobile device (iPhone 12 Pro) using my browser dev tools. The width of the iframe itself is not the problem here, but that the content inside the iframe apparently doesn't want to react responsively at such a narrow width.

Plus, it looks like this doesn't even let you overwrite the width - if I change it using browser dev tools, then it gets reset to 100% !important; immediately - so apparently this implementation has a script running in the background, that watches this, and resets the value automatically, if it gets overwritten from somewhere else.
